# WordPress 3.1 removing 'category' from the slug

Tags: customization, slug

Is there a way to remove 'category' from the slug when viewing posts in a particular category in WordPress 3.1 without it breaking? My client is asking me to remove it, but it seems necessary - I get a Page Not Found error when using this plugin:

http://fortes.com/projects/wordpress/top-level-cats/

He also doesn't want to just change it to another word...very frustrating...

Thanks,

osu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't test it myself, but maybe [this tip](http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/wpsnippets/~3/fZFjmTx8xxM/) could solve your problem:

> If you would like
>   yoursite.com/category/projects/projectname/
>   to appear as
>   yoursite.com/projects/projectname/
>
> Simply enter /. as the value for
>   Category base in the permalink
>   settings page.

Answer (score 2):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-category-base/
This seems to be an up to date plugin for the same thing

remove category base is probably what you want to search for if exploring other options

Comment: Thanks Rev Voodo, trying not to use a plugin if possible, but this is another good solution

Answer (score 0):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/ doing this and much more. Just disable metabox in edit pages, its working in stealth mode :)

Answer (score 0):

just install a plugin called "  WP No Category Base" on your wordpress blog and it will do all the work for you.

Comment: What *exctly* does the plugin do? Can you provide a link? How does this answer solve the problem?